# C# Access UNC folder with credentials only in Application context

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have made an application (in C #) for files backup. Suppose there is a NAS or a Windows Server, I want to save the zip files. In this place I do not want users to have access to specific unc folder (eg. \ 192.168.1.200 \ Backup ). Having the credentials for this folder, can I have access ONLY in the context of the application?
Some "solutions" that I found when the application has access to the folder (running) then the current user has access from the File Explorer. When the application is terminated after a bit lost and the current user access.